# .mouseenter and .mouseleave not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

lately I've been attempting to create a dropdown menu (I'm new to javascript and jQuery). I tried to do this using functions .mouseenter and .mouseleave in this way:

```
    $('.slideOne')
.mouseenter(function() {
    $('#one').animate({
    left: '10%'
    },100)
.mouseleave(function() {
    $('#one').animate({
    left: '-250px'
    },100);
    }); 
});
```

Everything works, but not really the way I expected it to. You can see the result on fiddle:

[Full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/filipbinkiewicz/1oLymcvo/embedded/result/)

and the full code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filipbinkiewicz/1oLymcvo/)

Hopefully you can see the ul's not necessarily appear when mouse is over the aproppriate li and they do not necessarily disappear after the mouse goes away.

Maybe someone has encoutered this problem? Or is there a better way for creating what I was trying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative way using `.hover()`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xm2eyzu3/)**

```
$('.slideOne').hover(function () {
    $('#one').animate({
        left: '10%'
    }, 100)
}, function () {
    console.log('dgfh');
    $('#one').animate({
        left: '-250px'
    }, 100);
});

$('.slideTwo').hover(function () {
    $('#two').animate({
        left: '14%'
    }, 100);
}, function () {
    $('#two').animate({
        left: '-250px'
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how come this works way much better that the '.mouseenter' method?

Comment: Because you haven't added your brackets correctly. Check for the closing brackets on `.mouseenter()` in you code. I haven't checked the rest of your code but I think it is the same problem every where.

Comment: Thank you. 
Could you also help me find a way to make the slideOne not disappear when the mouse goes from the menu to this div? I did it by adding the "slideOne" class to the sliding-in div, but it acts weird:

http://jsfiddle.net/filipbinkiewicz/1oLymcvo/11/

Comment: Just experiment with the `left` values. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w5tpe8r2/)**